# How to find steady state (stationary) solution of a stochastic differential equation?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stationary-processes, steady-state

i am trying to find steady state solution of a stochastic differential equation
$$
dy_t = \mathcal{A}\  y_s\  dt + \mathcal{B}_{1}\ y_s\ d\mu_{1}+ \mathcal{B}_{2t}\ y_s\ d\mu_{2t} \,\, ,
$$
where $\mathcal{A}$ , $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$ are operators , $d\mu_{1t}$ and $d\mu_{2t}$ are multiplicative white noises.
Is there any way or any literature where i can find some help for Steady state and stationary solution of SDE with multiplicative noises. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider formatting the formulas through LaTex as explained in this tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference